# Android upload many files / images at once to a servlet with parameters

Tags: java, android, servlets

This can be same and can be seen as duplicate since there are many questions about uploading an image. But I want to know how to upload MANY images at a time to a servlet.That said, if there are 6 images in SD card, all should be uploaded within one request,not one by one.  Most of samples over the internet are regarding one image or one file. I want to know if images are stored in a ArrayList, how they can be uploaded ?

In Servlet

```
  List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                                         new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

                for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                    if(!item.isFormField()){
                        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                        item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                      }
                }
```

This part works fine as I tested with normal JSP multiplart many images uploads.

In android for one image upload (took from  [another source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853033/server-sideservlet-code-for-upload-image-in-android)):

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName) );
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","Headers are written");
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            tv.append(inputLine);
        // close streams
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
```

This uploads only one image. How this can be used to send many with one POST request.? any other sample code or tutorial please.

Comment: There's a lot that could be going on here. If the event that posts the image is in a listview list item and you're not using the holder pattern it could cause it to fire multiple times. More context please. Maybe post your client and backend code.

Comment: You can either have a Web Service that allows posting one image and call it many times, or you can have one that accepts many images via POST.  I would opt for the single post called many times myself.

Comment: @JakeWilson801. Thanks for quick response. As you said, images are in a listview. How ever image pathes are kept in a seperate List and using that list (iterating...), images should be uploaded together.